# How to display digits as 99.1234564567891111 and not more than 13 decimal places in ag grid?

Tags: decimal, angular7, ag-grid

I want to restrict the input field in ag grid column and restrict to 13 decimal places as mentioned in the title.

Comment: you need to write custom `NumericCellEditor`(custom component) implementing your restriction in it.

Comment: yup..that is implemented already. Want to know the regex pattern or any alternative to restrict.

Answer (score 0):

though not related to AG-grid this regex `/(^\d{0,2})+(?:\.\d{1,13})?$/` should give you what you are looking for.

```js
console.log(/(^\d{0,2})+(?:\.\d{1,13})?$/.test("11.111111111111"));
console.log(/(^\d{0,2})+(?:\.\d{1,13})?$/.test("99.99999999999999"));
console.log(/(^\d{0,2})+(?:\.\d{1,13})?$/.test("11."));
```